# Bad Request and % in page address

Tags: php, unix

when i add in page address % get this error (www.mypage.com/news-360%-rotation):

> Bad Request
>
> Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
>
> Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)

This can by my php code error or something wrong with server settings?
And how fixt it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `%` character needs to be URL encoded. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding.

Try *www.mypage.com/news-360%25-rotation* instead.

Comment: Thanks, but still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use [urlencode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

```
'www.mypage.com/' . urlencode('news-360%-rotation');
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to URI encode the link, as the percentage symbol is "special" and used for encoding other values - I'd expect the URL to look more like:

`www.mypage.com/news-360%25-rotation`